# Want to call setupController or model hook

Tags: ember.js

I have following routes and controllers :

```
var App = App || Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('posts', function(){
    this.route('new', { path: '/new'});
  });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return $.getJSON('/api/posts');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    $.getJSON('/api/posts').done(function(data) {
      controller.set('model', data);
    });
});

App.PostsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addPost: function (file) {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/posts',
        data : {
         id: this.get('id'),
         title: this.get('title'),
         author: this.get('author'),
         contents: this.get('contents')
        }
      }).done(function(res){
        self.transitionToRoute('posts');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

What I want to do is calling 'posts' route to refresh post list in browser after user save new post successfully.

So I used "self.transitionToRoute('posts')" to call model hook or setupController in PostsRoute, but both methods never get called.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already on the posts route Ember doesn't see it necessary to refetch the model.  Additionally the controller has already been setup, and it already has the model, so it sees no reason to call it either.  Essentially it's avoiding wasting calls.  And personally I'd recommend avoiding adding the callback as well (unless you're expecting other posts from other users).

#### Example 1: Just add the new post to the list of current posts

```
needs: ['posts'],
actions:{
  addPost: function (file) {
    var self = this,
        data = {
          id: this.get('id'),
          title: this.get('title'),
          author: this.get('author'),
          contents: this.get('contents')
        };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/posts',
      data : data
    }).done(function(res){
      // just push the new data
      self.get('controllers.posts').pushObject(data);
      self.transitionToRoute('posts');
    });
  }
}
```

#### Example 2: Fetch all of the posts again, by sending an action, which will bubble up to the posts route

```
actions:{
  addPost: function (file) {
    var self = this,
        data = {
          id: this.get('id'),
          title: this.get('title'),
          author: this.get('author'),
          contents: this.get('contents')
        };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/posts',
      data : data
    }).done(function(res){
      self.send('updatePosts');
      self.transitionToRoute('posts');
    });
  }
}

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return $.getJSON('/api/posts');
  },
  actions: {
    updatePosts: function(){
      var controller = this.get('controller');
      this.model().then(function(data){
        controller.set('model', data);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k, the answer I was looking for !!

Comment: One quick question kingpin2k. In example #1, you pushed object into controller, not content or model. Does it automatically push into content? Can you elaborate more on it?

Comment: I'm assuming your posts controller is extending `Ember.ArrayController`.  Both the `ArrayController` and `ObjectController` are proxies, so when you set/get properties (or pushObjects) they are proxied down to the model/content below.